# Pass constructor values from subclass to superclass c++

Tags: c++, inheritance, constructor

I am writing a program where a superclass "Entry" simulates a library input where there are several subclasses. One of them is musicAlbum.

entry has a constructor with two string arguments to get the name of the borrowed item and the year. Then the subclass musicAlbum has a constructor to set several string parameters (artist and record label) as well as the parameters retrived in the superclass. However I get an error stating that there is no default constructor in the superclass so I believe I am doing something wrong that's very obvious but that I can't see.

Any help?

This is the superclass:

```
Class entry {

protected:
    int borrowed;
    string name, borrowedBy, year;

public:

entry(string cborrowedBy, string cyear) {
    borrowed = 1; //Borrowed changes to 1 to indicate that is currenty borrowed
    year = cyear;
    borrowedBy = cborrowedBy;
};    

virtual void entryBorrowed(string fname) {
    name = fname;
};
void entryReturned() {
    borrowed = 0;
}; // Calling this functions changes int borrowed into 0 to indicate that has been returned
virtual void printDetails() {};
```

};

This is the subclass:

```
    class musicAlbum : public entry {

protected: 

    string artist, recordLabel;

public:
    musicAlbum(string cmborrowedBy, string cmyear, string cartist, string crecordLabel){
         entry(cmborrowedBy, cmyear);
         artist = cartist;
         recordLabel = crecordLabel;

    }
    void entryBorrowed(string fname) {

        name = fname;



    }
    void printDetails() {

        cout << "This entry borrowed by: " << borrowedBy << " in " << year
            << endl << endl << "Name: " << name << endl << "Artist: " << artist << endl << "Record Label: " << recordLabel << endl;


    };


};
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can do it like this:

```
musicAlbum(string cmborrowedBy, string cmyear, string cartist, string crecordLabel):entry(cmborrowedBy, cmyear)
{
   //...
```